# Passing multiple strings to one option as an argument to a Perl script

Tags: perl, arguments, command-line-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getopt::Long getting a string with spaces into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108429/getoptlong-getting-a-string-with-spaces-into-a-variable)

Say I have the following Perl script:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std; 
use vars qw($opt_i $opt_o $opt_m); 
&getopts('i:o:m:'); 

say $opt_m
```

If I call this script with

```
perl script.pl -i text -o string -m hello how are you, world?
```

I don't get "hello how are you, world?" in `$opt_m`. How can I capture a string separated by whitespaces as one of the switch arguments to my script?

Comment: just minor: [use vars](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html) is obsolete, use our instead: `our ($opt_i, $opt_o, $opt_m) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to build the string

```
hello how are you, world?
```

So you have to use a string literal that builds that string. The syntax for string literals will vary by shell, but you can probably build that string using either of the following:

```
hello\ how\ are\ you,\ world\?
'hello how are you, world?'
```

Answer (score 4):

You would have to escape the spaces of the string:

```
hello\ how\ are\ you,\ world\?
```

Comment: `?` is special in most shells. You have to escape that too.

Comment: @scrappedcola In bash, if you use double quote, string start with $ is considered as envvar and will be interpreted.